# Add an icon to app

Tags: iphone, icons

I have an icon (57x57 pixels) which I copied to recources folder and added it to info.plist
but I don't see it on iPhone.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bible of app icons is [Apple's QA1686](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html). If you're sure that the file's in your project, and named in the Info.plist, my next question would be: is it a PNG file?

Answer (score 2):

Once in a while I have noticed that if you add an icon to your app and then run the app on your phone or on the simulator, that the icon will not show up. If this happens, I usually have to manually remove the app from the device or simulator to get the icon to appear.